# Changing the Cross-Hair Scale After the Update?

Tags: counter-strike-source

Since the large update Valve made to Counter-Strike Source about 6 months ago, I stopped playing for a bit. Now that I've come back, I've noticed something peculiar. I used to be able to change the size of my cross-hair with the command

```
cl_crosshairscale 20000
```

This would scale it down to as small as possible - the way I liked it. When I run that command now, the scale doesn't change. Is it still possible to change the scale? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Commands for setting crosshair properties have changed recently.

Check this sticky [thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1480629) for details.

As for your specific issue, setting `cl_legacy_crosshair_scale 1` will fix it.